# pull data from a remote wordpress database

Tags: database, sql

I am trying to pull some data from a remote wordpress database. Here is the code I have:

```
$server = "my server code";
$user = "my username";
$password = "my password";
$db = "mydb";
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password); 
if (!$con) {
    die("database connection error");

} else {

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

function dp_get_user_liked_posts($user_id, $fields = '') {

    global $wpdb;

    $tempDB = $wpdb;

$wpdb = new wpdb($user, $password, $db, $server);

    // Get user settings
    $settings = get_option('dp_post_likes');

        $login_required = !empty($settings['login_required']) ? true : false;

            if($login_required && !is_user_logged_in()) {

                echo '<p class="must-login">'.sprintf(__('You must <a href="%1$s">register</a> and <a href="%2$s">login</a> to view your liked videos.', 'dp'),  site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login'), wp_login_url()).'</p>';

            } else {

    $settings = get_option('dp_post_likes');
    $user = get_current_user_id();
    $user_id = 2;
    $likes=query_posts(array(
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                            'filter_type' => 'user_liked',
                            'filter_user' => $user_id
                        ));

                global $wp_query;
                 $likes= array();
                 while (have_posts()) : 
                            $likes[]=the_post() ;
                        endwhile;

}}}  
        mysql_close($con);

$wpdb = $tempDB;
```

but it is not display `$likes`. What is did wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. There are few things wrong here.

[`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) isn't mean to be used that way so don't. Try the same code with `$likes=new WP_Query(array(...` instead.

```
$likes=new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                        'filter_type' => 'user_liked',
                        'filter_user' => $user_id
                    ));
```

That is problem one. Then even if `$likes` were set correctly you'd clobber it.

```
$likes= array();
```

Why would you expect to have data in `$likes` after you've erased all of the data? Don't do that. Remove that line.

Now this:

```
while (have_posts()) : 
    $likes[]=the_post() ;
endwhile;
```

...is pointless. After you run the query `$likes` is already a collection of posts. Run `var_dump($likes)` and you will see what I mean. There is no need to loop over it just to do what is already been done. Just return `$likes` or loop over it and do something, like echo content.

Besides, using `the_post` like that wouldn't work. That isn't what the `the_posts` method does.

If, on the other hand, you are trying to extract, for example, the post content you'd want...

```
while ($likes->have_posts()) : 
    $likes->the_post();
    $cont[] = $post->post_content;
endwhile;
```

I'd really suggest you take some time to read about [creating loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops).

You can do about the same with [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) but the loops are a little different.

Also, why are you mixing PHP's `mysql_*` functions with `$wpdb`? And why are you using `global $wpdb` only to then clobber it? Why don't you just use a different name for your database instance?

Hopefully that helps.